# No SQS event published when a new file upload to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs, aws-cli, boto3

Today I encountered an issue and I'm not if there's a solution or is it a bug.

In our project we use `S3` and `SQS` and `API Gateway` as an interface for `S3`. Whenever a new file is uploaded via gateway a new event is being published to `SQS` and there are no problems.

Earlier today I deployed a new version of our service and consumes `SQS` messages. To test that everything works as expected I created a new `S3` bucket and corresponding `SQS` queue. Than I started to copy objects from production bucket to the newly created one using `boto3` Python library.

After a while I noticed that for some files there was no SQS event published. And after research it turned out that all such files are greater than `8Mb`.

I also tried to upload a file using `AWS CLI` just in case, but result was the same.

However, when I upload a file from AWS web console, then I can see `SQS` event published.

So everything works when uploading to `S3` via `API Gateway` or `AWS Web Console` but not `AWS CLI` or `boto3` and presumably other libraries.
Seems like a bug or some limitation but I couldn't find any documentation on it.

Has anyone experienced similar behaviour?

Thanks in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe 8MB is the size at which the CLI (and SDK) will start performing multi-part upload operations. You probably need to enable notifications for the `s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload` event on your S3 bucket.

Comment: Yes, that helped! Thanks again!